Rendering with Transparency produces black & white image
I'm using the Transparency option under the Film tab, the viewport shows the image/animation in color but when I save the image and render the animation the PNGs are black and white, grateful if anyone has any advice.


First thing have you enabled PNG > RGBA? Otherwise it won't be transparent

I have done that. I've tried with Cycles and Eeevee as well and both give me black and white results. Thanks

It has to do with the Emssion node, it won't work on transparent background

Thank you for your time, is there a way to achieve an Emission effect without the Node -  Principle BSDF Emission? Thanks

Do you really need transparency? Or can you overlay the image on its background in the Compositor?

I do need the Transparency as I'm using several images each emitting light (hologram effect) in an animated sequence. I thought that if I can use separate passes on each image I can then composite them in Da Vinchi and be able to control the emission of each layer without the issue of the images blowing each other out as they are effected by their respective lights. Not sure if that's the best way but it's not something I've tried before. Thank you again for your time.

You can use some tricks to fix that but it's a bit tedious, that's a limitation of Blender (or rather of the image formats)
